# Why is -g flag prevents precompiled header from being used?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, g++, precompiled-headers

When I precompiled the `stdc++.h` header, I notice that if I compile as usual the log shows that the PCH is being used

```
g++ -H -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main
```

output

```
! bits/stdc++.h.gch
 main.cpp
```

However, if I added the -g flag which I usualy have for projects on VSCode, which per g++ documentation says is to provide debugging feature for gbd

```
g++ -g -H -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main
```

the output shows the precompiled header is not being used

```
x bits/stdc++.h.gch
. bits/stdc++.h
...
```

Comment: Yiu should probably use *the same* option flags for the precompiled header. Otherwise is doesn't match the code in the rest of the program.

Comment: I tried to compile both with -g flag but that would cause error whenever I try to build